# Showing an alert message over a different window

Tags: javascript, window.open

Is it possible to open an alert message over another window?  I do a `window.open()` then I show an alert message.  But that alert message brings me back to the window containing the javascript that displayed the message.  This behavior makes sense.  But I want to display help message for the new window that is currently being shown to the user.  Is there a way to get that functionality with `alert()` or is there a different way to do that?

```
window.open(url, _blank);
alert('Do step 1, then step 2, then step 3 to get to the page'); 
// The step above returns the focus to the original window
```

Is there a way around that?

** EDIT **

Got the answer from Musa but had to modify it because I was using setTimeout and ran into browser suppression issues.  Normally, his answer should work.  Here is the code that worked.

```
    external_window = window.open(url,'_blank'); // Open external window.
    message_window = window.open (url,'_blank','width=600,height=200,top=200,left=300'); // Open message window.
    self.focus(); // Keep focus on original window.
    setTimeout(function() { external_window.focus(); message_window.focus(); }, 4000); // After delay, focus on external window, then on message window
```

This has the right effect while getting around the browser suppression issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newWindow = window.open(url, _blank);
newWindow.alert('Do step 1, then step 2, then step 3 to get to the page');
```

Comment: Because I must do this in setTimeout() the alert doesn't display.  The browser suppresses it.  Is there a different way that I could show a message to the user from that window?

Comment: To get around the browser suppression issue, I did the alert with a second window.open: `var message_window = window.open(url,'blank');`.  Then I did `external_window.focus();` followed by `message_window.focus();` to have the message appear on top of the relevant window.  Both within a setTimeout function to get the desired delay. See Edit in original question for the actual code.